# Implicit Dependencies of Java Classes with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, oop, modularity

I opted for Maven to take advantage of software modularity by using Module Projects on Eclipse.

Indeed, I have a root project that contains the common dependencies in pom.xml, which are implicitly recognizable by sub-modules.

I would like to know if the same happens with my own java classes/interfaces, or do I have to explicitly include root project to sub-module projects in the classpath?

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the packaging structure of your root module and sub-module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use classes from one module in other module, you need to add that module as a dependency. Your root project dependencies are available to your sub-modules, but that may not be necessarily true for your classes/interfaces.